# The fastest way to create a new column in the pandas dataframe that satisfies two conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a new column ('new_date') in pandas based on the conditions on the other two columns ('date' and 'hour'), which are integers. My code is doing what I need but it's too **SLOW** for big dataframes. Please see my code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date': [20150101, 20150102, 20150103, 20150104, 20150105], 'hour': [113000, 142500,170000,235999,81500]})

def convert_date(row):
    if row['hour']!=235999:
        val = pd.to_datetime(row['date'], format='%Y%m%d') # convert the integer to date format
    else:
        val = pd.to_datetime(row['date'], format='%Y%m%d')+pd.offsets.BDay(1) # convert the integer to date format and add one business day
    return val

start_time = time.time()
df['new_date']= df.apply(convert_date, axis=1)
print(round(time.time() - start_time,2), 'Seconds')
```

I also used this code which is too slow too!

```
df['new_date']= df.apply(lambda row: pd.to_datetime(row['date'], format='%Y%m%d') if row['hour']!=235999 else pd.to_datetime(row['date'], format='%Y%m%d')+pd.offsets.BDay(1), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the function with the following approach using [`.loc()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). That way you wouldn't have to loop throw individual rows.

```py
df['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
df.loc[df['hour'] == 235999, 'new_date'] += pd.offsets.BDay(1)
```

You can also use the [`df.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) method

```py
df['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
df['new_date'] = df['new_date'].where(df['hour'] != 235999, df['new_date'] + pd.offsets.BDay(1))
```

Both approaches are more efficient than your costume function.

Comment: @ Jamiu S., Many thanks for your help. The first approach is faster. Thanks